# How to make rendering loop selections work in Movie Studio Platinum 13?

Tags: vegas-pro

I want to render just 10 seconds of my 1920x1080 movie to create the best quality preview for a demo. But rendering process takes the same time as rendering the entire movie (35 minutes).

Why is it taking so long?

A guess - is Movie Studio rendering the entire file and then just cropping away the unselected part? How do I render the selection only?

Here is what I do:

- select a 10 seconds region in the timeline
- go to menu -> Project -> Make movie
- pick option Save it to my hard drive
- pick format mp4
- **enable the checkbox "Render loop region only"**
- click Advanced options and pick Sony AVC/MVC encoder
- pick my preset of choice (1440x1080@30p, 1.333 pixel ratio for anamorphic aspect ratio, 25 FPS, 26 Mbps bitrate)
- render

Comment: Make sure that a loop region is highlighted when you click on Make Movie. When you render, are you viewing the render preview? How fast is the output progressing?

Comment: Yes, the loop region is highlighted. I just tried to select a region further in the video and render it again with the checkbox enabled, but the preview window shows as if it is rendering the video from the very beginning of it! Maybe there is some hidden setting which forces it to render entire video even for loops?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I found it myself and leaving the answer here in case someone else will get confused by this because the solution is not obvious.

I was setting the checkbox here:

[image: Wrong checkbox]

but if I use "Advanced options", **Movie Studio ignores this setting!**

I have to select it deeper in a hidden dropdown in the "Advanced options" window like this:

[image: Right checkbox]

And later when rendering the full video, it is important to remember to open that dropdwon again and turn off the region rendering.

Oh, Sony, this is so confusing - two things doing the same, but effective only under specific circumstances.